# Regular expression that will catch strings containing 2 specific words

Tags: regex

I am trying to come up with a regular expression that will catch this string:

```
must-c046-was001-ix.1.oca.best.net
```

The strings to catch will always contain `must` and `best` (always in that order, `must` before `best`), but the words and numbers between them may vary.

I need to catch all strings that qualify; including the characters after `best`.

Comment: Could you explain the string to be catched better? So far this regexp `must-c046-was001-ix.1.oca.best.net ` would match your sample.

Comment: @M.Becerra `must-c046-was001-ix\.1\.oca\.best\.net1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String to catch:

```
must-c046-was001-ix.1.oca.best.net
```

Regex (PCRE form):

```
/must-[a-z0-9-.]+best[a-z.]+/
```

The [regex explainer here](https://regexr.com/) will help to decipher it.

It will find a string with "must-" at the start followed by at least one lowercase-letter, number, dash, or dot; then "best" followed by at least one letter or dot. I'd use the "g" option at the end normally but if you're using some systems that won't work, eg [kpcre](https://github.com/xnsystems/kpcre/wiki) doesn't include that option, but includes for example "i" (as the last character after the slash to make the match case-insensitive.

Comment: one question i'm trying to make it work in iptables, but doesnt , can you help ? 

rule is :

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m string --string "/must-[a-z0-9-\.]+best[a-z\.]+/g" --algo regex -p tcp -m tcp --dport 230 -j DNAT --to-destination 5.5.5.5:230

Comment: i cant add the rule above, if i use a different algo like kmp or bm regular expression does not take effect

Comment: IMO you always should put your goal and not [only] a sub-goal. `iptables` matches don't work like that normally you need the `kpcre` kernel module installed (eg [kpcre](https://github.com/xnsystems/kpcre/wiki/iptables-string-regex)) but I don't think they're default, not in Ubuntu. My regex is in PCRE format, so perhaps try ["--algo pcre"](https://github.com/xnsystems/kpcre/wiki) as in that Wiki link. You could use Wireshark to capture packets, then do static analysis to verify the regex is matching. I do see you need to ditch the "global" option as that's not in kpcre, answer amended.

Comment: Looks like /A is a close kpcre equivalent of /g; basically once it's matched it won't look for more matches, which is probably what you're after to make things faster.

Comment: i managed to install kpre but still wont catch strings as per regex